# Concatenar textos de Userform e inserir como link em uma célula

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, userform

Estou tentando alimentar uma tabela com 3 informações inseridas a partir da execução de um Userform e, ao fim, fazer um hiperlink direto na célula com as informações inseridas. As informações são as seguintes:

1. Caminho para uma determinada pasta (textbox)
2. Os 2 primeiros caracteres de uma opção selecionada (combobox)
3. Data e hora correntes

O que eu fiz basicamente para obter isso foi o seguinte:

```
Cells(LRow, 1).Formula = "=Hyperlink(""H:\backup\test\"")"
Cells(LRow, 2).Value = UCase(Left(Me.Cbx_State.Value, 2))
Cells(LRow, 3).Value = Format(Now, "_yyyymmdd_hhmmss")
Cells(LRow, 1) = Cells(LRow, 1) & Cells(LRow, 2) & Cells(LRow, 3)
```

Quando eu rodo apenas a primeira linha, o link funciona perfeitamente para a pasta, contudo, ao rodar a quarta (em que concateno as duas outras informações, o link para de funcionar.

Eu esperava obter um link assim, por exemplo:

```
H:\backup\test\CT-20170322_162111
```

Eu não entendo o problema. Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que vc está concatenando uma fórmula com outros textos e, como a fórmula transforma o conteúdo selecionado em um link, as coisas estão se confundindo. Vc deveria fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

Primeiro insira os valores da coluna 2 e 3, e em seguida monte o conteúdo da coluna 1, que será o link:

```
Cells(LRow, 2).Value = UCase(Left(Me.Cbx_State.Value, 2))
Cells(LRow, 3).Value = Format(Now, "_yyyymmdd_hhmmss")
Cells(LRow, 1).Formula = "=Hyperlink(""H:\backup\test\" & Cells(LRow, 2) & Cells(LRow, 3) & """)"
```

Caso não queira uma linha de comando tão grande, declare uma variável para substituir a parte concatenada, desse modo:

```
Cells(LRow, 2).Value = UCase(Left(Me.Cbx_State.Value, 2))
Cells(LRow, 3).Value = Format(Now, "_yyyymmdd_hhmmss")
Dim c As String: c = Cells(LRow, 2) & Cells(LRow, 3)
Cells(LRow, 1).Formula = "=Hyperlink(""H:\backup\test\" & c & """)"
```

Isso deve resolver seu problema!